# Magento Redirect https to http home page

Tags: .htaccess, http, magento, https, singlepage

Google has indexed the home page of my website with https. But I need to redirect https to http only this page. I'm using Magento and today I have a rule that removes the htaccess www of my domain. Every rule I created to redirect the main page of https to http didn't work. 
Anyone have a solution?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
#Redirect your Homepage from HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

See http://www.activo.com/redirect-https-to-http-for-any-homepage/

Answer (score 1):

**Set this up in Magento first:**

Oopen admin panel and visit **`System -> Configration -> Web panel`** and set:

- Base URL (unsecured) as `http://www.domain.com/magento/`.
- Base URL (secured) as `https://www.domain.com/magento/`.

then set:

- Use Secure URLs in Frontend = Yes
- Save your settings, clear your Magento cache

**Finally in Magento's .htaccess add these lines just below RewriteBase line:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (?!^(index\.php/?|.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.gif|.*\.jpe?g|.*\.png|.*\.txt|.*\.ico|)$)^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/?|.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.gif|.*\.jpe?g|.*\.png|.*\.txt|.*\.ico|)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: I'm using onestepcheckout and need https in frontend to use this feature.

Comment: Your home page is also part of front end isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this with 301 http request for google indexer.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use cludeflare then this redirect is not working

place try with below on you htaccess file  and it cloudflare format

**Http to Https   redirection:**

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

**See note:**

When using Flexible SSL with CloudFlare, your origin server will always accept requests over HTTP (port 80). In order to properly redirect a user surfing securely over HTTPS, you should modify your rewrite rules to use the CF-Visitor HTTP header. The CF-Visitor header contains the following:

```
CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"}
```

or
    CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}

To redirect a user from HTTP to HTTPS, you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Similarly, to require all traffic go over HTTPS on CloudFlare, you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !'"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```