# Magento site redirects to home page when ssl is enabled

Tags: magento, ssl, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1.0 and i have enabled SSL. SSL is purcahsed from Godady and is installed and configured at the server. 
I have also set the Base URL in secure section to https://..... . Now when i enable it for front end, and then when i try to go to customer login page (which is served by https), i am always redirected to home page.

I have applied a few fixes, but no one worked.

The fix described on the below link starts a redirect loop and the site never loads.

[Magento HTTPS on all website: urls redirect to homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527671/magento-https-on-all-website-urls-redirect-to-homepage)

Also i have read the following:

http://www.aschroder.com/2012/07/magento-ssl-offloading-with-amazon-elb/

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/ssl-issues-with-magento-behind-load-balancer-302-loop

http://blog.ideaday.de/max/2012/12/magento-https-redirect-loop-ssl-offloading-proxies-pound-nginx/

https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-https-redirect-loop/

http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/magento-redirection-loop-problem-after-installing-ssl/

And no fix is working for me.

Now i am offering a 50 points bounty for the correct answer.

Can someone give me some idea how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043266/magento-redirect-https-to-http-home-page
You may try the solution given in the above link.

Comment: Hi, did you addressed this issue to Godaddy, did you cross verify hosting configuration from them after applying SSL certificate ?

Comment: @BikramShrestha, It is also tried, and it generates a redirect loop and page never load, even home page

Comment: @Chiragit007 , No, the problem is not from godaddy side, it is from magento side. I am using this same ssl on an other website in a subfolder of the domain, and it works fine there.

Comment: Curiosity, is this a multi-store? Second question, are you using a stock .htaccess file?

Comment: @altafhussain, are you already logged in the site when you accessing the login url? If yes it will redirect the user to "My Account page", but not to home page. Kindly confirm

Comment: @Rob yes this is a multistore . We are using the htaccess which comes with magento.

Comment: @ManafPM When i enable SSL, i even cant go to login page, so i cant login to the website.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem while on a login form submitted via ajax, the login form was loaded as part of a http page as opposed to https, which is not good, and then the login form data submitted by ajax to a https controller url.  on success some javascript would try to load a https landing page into the main window.

The problem was magento would redirect the landing page which is what you're experiencing.

To solve hte issues, we loaded the login form by https and dynamically put it into the dom.  We used the form action to a https link, and a form submit rather than an ajax post.  Then the magento controller would use a redirect in the response to the landing page or an error page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your system->confi->web->Session Validation Settings

Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT
this two fields are enable so only disable it ! :)